# How to compare a string with a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, function, compare

I would like to compare a string with a list, but my code isn't working

```
def compare(typeOfColors):
   introduceC = input("Introduce a color")
   while(introduceC.lower() != typeOfColors)
       print("Error")
colors = ["white", "black"] 
compare(colors)
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `for` statement? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: `introduceC.lower() in typeOfColors` is enough to know if the lower version of the input string is present in the list

Answer (score 1):

Use the `in` keyword to test if an array contains a value.

```
def compare(typeOfColors):
   introduceC = input("Introduce a color")
   while introduceC.lower() not in typeOfColors:
       print("Error")
colors = ["white", "black"] 
compare(colors)
```

But that introduces a new error, infinite looping, which you could solve like this:

```
def compare(typeOfColors):
    introduceC = input("Introduce a color: ")
    if introduceC.lower() not in typeOfColors:
       print("Error")
       return compare(typeOfColors)

    print('Exists!')
    return introduceC

colors = ["white", "black"] 
compare(colors)
```

Giving:

```
Introduce a color: red
Error
Introduce a color: blue
Error
Introduce a color: whitE   
Exists!
```

If the user inputs something that is not in the accepted values, the function calls itself, effectively restarting. That is recursion.

Comment: *introduceC* never change => you loop without ending if the test is false

Comment: @bruno, I did mention as much, in any case I gave a more complete solution now.

Comment: Thanks, but i want the program to ask again for a color if its not in the list

Comment: @BRT88 It does ask again, try it!

Answer (score 1):

To know if a string is in *typeOfColors* just use `in`

Note *introduceC* is unchanged in your loop, so if `introduceC.lower() != typeOfColors`is false you loop without ending

To loop until the input is part of the list you can just do

```
def compare(typeOfColors):
   while (not input("Introduce a color: ").lower() in typeOfColors):
       print("Error")

compare(["white", "black"])
```

Example

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def compare(typeOfColors):
...    while (not input("Introduce a color: ").lower() in typeOfColors):
...        print("Error")
... 
>>> compare(["white", "black"])
Introduce a color: blue
Error
Introduce a color: red
Error
Introduce a color: bLack
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through each element of the list.
Then for each element comparing that with the color.

I'll try to help you if you need more than that.

Comment: there is no need top loop on the list, `in` will do that for you

Comment: But if i do a for loop, maybe the correct color is the last one, but i will have previous "Error" messages from the others

Comment: I don't really understand what you want then.